# Regex to match emotions

Tags: java, regex, twitter

I have to remove the Twitter emoticons in a tweet. Those emoticons are formed using the following 8 characters:

```
: " - ^ ; ) ' (
```

and an emotion has a length of at least 2.

Comment: Make an array of all emoticons and use a simple replace. This will prevent the deletion of valid special characters.

Comment: You're absolutely right. but if there is any emotion there, it will cause serious error :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming emoticons end in `)` or `(`, and start in `:` or `;`, with the other characters in the middle, you could try:

```
[:;]+["^-]*[()]+
```

Comment: You could use `[()]` instead of escaping.

Comment: @Jerry How could that ever be distinguishable, with or without a regex.

Comment: Just saying that those kinds of emotes also exist and I can assure you a lot of people use those over the more conventional `:)` (a habit sometimes obtained to avoid the auto replace of the text version of emotes to pictures they don't like).

Comment: @arshajii: I am sorry can you edit alittle bit to match repeatition  :)))) or ::")

Comment: @HoaVu Is something like `:^()` or `:;")` allowed? If so, this should work, otherwise try `(?::+|;+)["^-]*(?:\(+|\)+)`.

Comment: @arshajii It works . To be honest, you have me so much. Thank you :-)